# plot a dirac function which is in symbolic - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using this code:

```
syms x
ezplot(dirac(x-2))
```

the function is always 0 and 1 at x=2. but the drawn figure is 0 everywhere. how to draw it correctly?

Comment: A dirac function is infinite where it's not zero. how were you wanting it plotted?
One convention when plotting a dirac function is to draw an arrow whose height is the integral of the dirac function.

Comment: oh you are right. actually I expected it to be 1 where it is infinite. is that possible? or how can I have that arrow?

Answer (score 0):

In case your value is limited by being a symbolic variable you can first change it to a double format, then do the rest in a similar way.
See

```
syms x
x=2;
s= double(x);
s=2;
smin=s-15;
smax=s+15;
p=smin:0.01:smax;
q = double(p == 2);
plot(p, q);
```

And by having +-15 you are basically creating a range around your dirac function input.